# Merge Rows within Data Frame [some fields duplicate]

Tags: r

I have 3 columns. name, review, part in a data.frame  (set)

```
        name     review             part
 1      abc      this is good       cap   
 2      abc      this is not bad    cap
 3      abc      this is also good  cap
```

I  want the end result to look like this:

```
       name     review                 part
  1    abc      this is good this      cap
                is not bad this is 
                also good
```

Comment: What is the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your columns are of class `character`, you could do something like this:

```
df[sapply(df, duplicated)] <- ""
> df
#  name            review part
#1  abc      this is good  cap
#2        this is not bad     
#3      this is also good
```

Comment: i don't want 2 and 3 row.  data combine in 1st row only. 
              as i show in top. please check ones. thanks

Comment: `df$review[1] <- paste(df$review,collapse=";")`
and `df[1,]`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming "review" column is of factor type

```
require(plyr)
df$review <- as.character(df$review)

ddply(df, .(name, part), summarize, review = paste(review, collapse = " "))[,c(1,3,2)]
```